# Assigning a User Id to a Nested Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Using Rails 4 with Devise

I have a Post model and a Comment model. Comments are nested into Posts. I have assigned posts to a user, but having trouble assigning comments to a user since it is nested.

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
```

post.rb:

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

comment.rb:

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

In my comments_controller.rb I have tried using current_user like this:

```
def new
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
  @comment = current_user.post.comments.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
  end
end

def create
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.post.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@comment.post, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @comment, :status => :created, :location => [@comment.post, @comment] }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

but i receive this error:

```
undefined method `post' for #<User:0x00000103300a30>
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be **posts**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@comment = post.comments.build
```

instead of

```
@comment = current_user.post.comments.build
```

it doesn't work like that.

you've already told it what `post` is so do you expect `current_user.post` to return something different?

```
def create
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@comment.post, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment, :status => :created, :location => [@comment.post, @comment] }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

instead of

```
def create
  post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = current_user.post.comments.create(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@comment.post, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment, :status => :created, :location => [@comment.post, @comment] }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes you are right. How can I assign the comment to a user?

Comment: Awesome thank you. Do I need to include `@comment.user = current_user` in the new action as well? I don't think I do but just making sure. And i apologize I am new to rails and still need to read the rails guide.

Comment: no worries. you're correct, current_user is known on the server side so there's no use putting it in the new action.